# Creating a variable sized array in C

Tags: c

I want to do matrix multiplication with variable sized arrays in C, however I can't initialize the matrix variable.

Here is the code:

```
printf("Enter dimensions of matrix A: ");
scanf("%d %d", &p, &q);
printf("Enter number of columns of matrix B: ");
scanf("%d", &r);

int A[p][q] = {{}};
int B[q][r] = {{}};
int C[p][r] = {{}};
```

I searched for similar queries online however, most deal with one dimensional arrays or two dimensional square arrays.
What should I do?

Comment: Variable-length array can't be initialized when you define them. You need code to do the initialization.

Comment: I added the code as text.

Comment: Also note for normal arrays, ISO C forbids empty initializer braces... That is a compiler extension. For normal 2D arrays, at least use `{{0}}`. For VLA, after declaration, you can use `memset()` to zero the array, e.g. `memset (A, 0, sizeof A);`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin -- empty initializer braces were added for C23, but I don't know that compilers are really supporting it yet.

Comment: Why do you need to initialize them? Isn't the values coming from some kind of input (stdin or a file)? And if you really need to initialize, what value do you want? zero?

Comment: OT: Using user input for VLA dimensions without some check for maximum values is bad... very bad

Comment: @adabsurdum - yep, but I guarantee you the code above wasn't compiled with `-std=c23`... It will take a while until there is full compiler support for C23.

Answer (score 3):

Variable Length Arrays (VLA) cannot be *initialized* in C.  (C23 may allow zero initializations.)

Instead *assign* values.

```
printf("Enter dimensions of matrix A: ");
if (scanf("%d %d", &p, &q) == 2 && p > 0 && q > 0) {
  int A[p][q]; // Cannot initialize here.

  // Zero the whole array.
  memset(A, 0, sizeof A);

  // ... or assign individual elements.
  for (int ip = 0; ip < p; ip++) {
    for (int iq = 0; iq < q; iq++) {
      A[ip][iq] = rand(); // Assign a value.
    }
  }

  ... // Use `A[][]`
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Array pointers come to the rescue :)

```
    int (*A)[q] = calloc(p, sizeof(*A));
    int (*B)[r] = calloc(q, sizeof(*B));
    int (*C)[r] = calloc(p, sizeof(*C));
```

It allocates 2D array (as a chunk of memory) and initialises it to `0`. You access the array the normal way - ie `A[x][y]`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't try `malloc`?

```
printf("Enter dimensions of matrix A: ");
scanf("%d %d", &p, &q);
printf("Enter number of columns of matrix B: ");
scanf("%d", &r);

int *A[p];
for (int i=0; i<p; ++i)
    A[i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*q);

int *B[q];
for (int i=0; i<q; ++i)
    B[i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*r);

int *C[p];
for (int i=0; i<p; ++i)
    C[i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*r);
```

Do not forget to free it before the function finished :)

```
for (int i=0; i<p; ++i)
    free(A[i]);
for (int i=0; i<q; ++i)
    free(B[i]);
for (int i=0; i<p; ++i)
    free(C[i]);
```

Comment: This isn't a 2d array, either. What you have is a peculiar mixture of  _variable length arrays_  with what are often called _jagged arrays_. Arrays consist of contiguous storage, but jagged arrays contain pointers to memory that may not be contiguous. One issue with this is that spreading the memory out has negative performance implications. You might take a look at [this useful Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays).

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, memory allocation is possibly the way to go.

It might help to organize things a bit more clearly. For example, with the datatypes

```c
typedef int Cell;
typedef Cell* Row;
typedef struct {
  int rows;
  int columns;
  Row* data;
} Matrix;
```

we could initialize and destroy matrices using

```c
void initMatrix(Matrix* p) {
  p->data = malloc(sizeof(Row) * p->rows);
  for (int r = 0; r < p->rows; r++) {
    p->data[r] = calloc(p->columns, sizeof(Cell));
  }
}

void destroyMatrix(Matrix* p) {
  for (int r = 0; r < p->rows; r++) {
    free(p->data[r]);
  }
  free(p->data);
}
```

which might make working with the matrices simpler; for example:

```c
int main() {
  int p, q;
  printf("Enter dimensions of matrix A: ");
  scanf("%d %d", &p, &q);

  Matrix A = {.rows = p, .columns = q};
  initMatrix(&A);
  A.data[2][2] = 5; // Assuming, of course...
  // ...
  destroyMatrix(&A);
}
```